# run the zephir language on windows machines

Tags: windows, installation, package, zephir

Is it possible to use the [zephir language](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir) on a windows system when the packages [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) and [re2c](http://re2c.org/) are required.

Can I somehow install or build the packages in windows to then build and run zephir?

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs in windows. There are sources and binaries of json-c and re2c, and zephir itself is documented to compile under Visual C. I see no reason for it to not run on windows.

Comment: I have never build a php extension on windows before. I just didn't want to put effort into it if it wasn't possible.